# Find the values of the parameter p, with which the equation $\frac{(x-8)(x-4p)}{x^2-16x+48}=0$ has one root.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the values of the parameter p, with which the equation $\frac{(x-8)(x-4p)}{x^2-16x+48}=0$ has one root.

I know that, if Discriminant is equal to $0$ then equation has $1$ root. But what if we have a fraction ?
Please provide me with a hint.

Comment: HINT: What happens when some $x$ cancels both numerator and denominator?

Comment: Also consider the case when the Nr has a double root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a rational function equation:
$$
\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)} = 0,
$$

it is effectively the same as two equations:
$$
\begin{cases}P(x) = 0,\\Q(x)\neq 0.\end{cases}
$$

So either $P(x)$ has 1 root which isn't the root of $Q(x)$ or all but 1 root of $P(x)$ are the roots of $Q(x)$

Comment: Now I understand how to find p. I need to find the sum of all p's. My textbook answer says it is 6. Is there a mistake, since I found that only $p=2$ ?

Comment: Check  hamam_Abdallah solution

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2-16x+48=x^2-16x+64-16$$
$$=(x-8)^2-16$$
$$=(x-8+4)(x-8-4)$$
$$=(x-4)(x-12)$$

So, if $ x\ne 4$ and $ x\ne 12$,

$$\frac{(x-8)(x-4p)}{x^2-16x+48}=0$$
$$\iff (x-4)(x-4p)=0$$
$$\iff x=8 \vee x=4p$$
where $ p\ne 1$ and $ p\ne 3$.
If $ p=1 $ or $ p=3 $ then $ x=8 $ is the unique root.

There will be one root if $$4p=8 \vee p=1 \vee  p=3$$

Comment: This isn't correct. There will be one root if $p = 1,2,3$.